# How to launch app from outside with BOOT_COMPLETED in android 10 and above versions

Tags: android, android-tv, launch, bootcompleted

How to launch application, if my device is Android tv?
in android version of 9 and lower this code workid, but higher versions the application do not launching. Is any solutions?

```
`class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            Log.w("bootbroadcastpoc", "starting service...");

            if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                val intent = Intent(context, KioskActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                context.startActivity(intent)


            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I also tried to start the service and from the service launch my application, but that also did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app runs in the background. There are several [solutions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions), but I think the easiest way is to request [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission.

Comment: thanks, I have requested the  SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW  permission in my activity, and after restarting the app launched.