# How to automatically launch an app when an Android phone boots up for Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hello awesome developers! As you can see, I'd like to ensure my application starts when the phone boots up. Everything else is functioning correctly; I receive toasts and background processes are working. However, my application fails to run. What could be the issue, and how can I fix it? Thank you.

```
class BootCompleteReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val mainIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context?.startActivity(mainIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

     <receiver
         android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"
         android:exported="false"
             android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
         <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AutoBootTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }

        }


    }

}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    AutoBootTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch app from outside with BOOT\_COMPLETED in android 10 and above versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78184944/how-to-launch-app-from-outside-with-boot-completed-in-android-10-and-above-versi)

Comment: Sadly no, I'm looking for the solution, do you have any idea ?

Comment: You cannot launch activities from the background in most cases on modern versions of Android. If you want to control the UI when the phone starts, make your activity be the launcher.

Comment: My active is already launcher but it doesn'tapp the app when phone boots up